# Is it possible to link three.js to Mapbox React Native

Tags: react-native, three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to link [three.js](https://threejs.org) to [mapbox](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl) React Native SDK.

I have seen the plugin threebox, but that is to link specifically to mapbox gl js.

I'm looking to add a custom 3d model (i.e. an airplane) to a mapbox React Native SDK map.